# Is it acceptable to use different size units in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have been doing a project using Bootstrap. To set the paddings I used %. I created a countdown timer in JavaScript. The % unit is everywhere except for two padding (in the intervals between clock numbers).

I realize that it is wrong to use different units, but in this case using % causes problems (even the smallest value of 1% gives too much spacing) that's why I set the px and it works.

Is there another way to do it "correctly"? (I don't want to use only px).

```css
#cta {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.cta-heading {
  font-family: "Montserrat-black";
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#cta>.container-fluid {
  color: #258382;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 15%;
}

.time {
  padding-right: 10px;
  /* I set the pixels, % are too big */
}

.day,
.hour,
.minute,
.second {
  color: #1E4C4C;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-right: 10px;
  /* the same, it works, but I have objections about this */
}

#cta h2 {
  padding: 3%;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffbf00;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#cta p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="cta">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Time to summer e-Xperience</h2>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
      <div class="day"></div>
      <span class="time">days</span>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
        <div class="hour"></div>
        <span class="time">hours</span>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
          <div class="minute"></div>
          <span class="time">minutes</span>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
            <div class="second"></div>
            <span class="time">seconds</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap comes with padding classes. For bootstrap 4 and below, you can use **pr-[value]** to add extra padding to the right, where value is any integer number from 0 to 5. Similarly, you can also add padding to the left with **pl-[value]** on Bootstrap 4, **px-[value]** to add margin to the left and right or py to add padding to the top and bottom.

For Bootstrap 5 instead of **pl** you use **ps** which stands for padding-start or **pe** for padding-right(padding-end). I hope this helps you.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/